# Codeigniter Login controller views

Tags: codeigniter

```
function index()
{
    # code...
    $this->load->view('signin');

    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('LoginModal');

        if ($this->LoginModal->login_valid($username, $password)) {
            # code...
            echo "Login Succesfully";
        }
        else
        {
            $wrong = "Wrong Credentials";

            $this->load->view('signin',['wrong'=>$wrong]);
        }

}
```

This is my controller in codeiniter i want to pass wrong credentials values to the views if the login password is wrong but it shows two views of the same page if the login credentials are wrong

Kindly please help me 
Thanks
Regards

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my proposal. Enjoy coding in codeigniter.

```
<?php
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('LoginModal');
    $data = array();
    $data['wrong'] = '';
    # code...
    if($this->input->post()) {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if ($this->LoginModal->login_valid($username, $password)) {
            # code...
            echo "Login Succesfully";
            //maybe redirect if you want
            redirect('../home', 'refresh');
        } else {
            $data['wrong'] = "Wrong Credentials";
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('signin',$data);
}
```